# How to access the web page contents

Tags: java, html, web, web-crawler, jsoup

I am storing text of a webpage in a string . but some contents of the web page is not stored in the string. I don't know why the contents in a div like elements are not stored. Even the links inside the div is not accessible using a web crawler that i have implemented. Can anyone help me out with this!!!.

```
 List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("some link here").get();
Elements taglinks = doc.select("html");
for (Element link : taglinks) {
tags.add(link.text());}
System.out.println(tags);
```

Comment: Can you share some code what your tried till now?

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of adding your code in the comments

Comment: it works for some of the links but not all the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear enough, but from your codes I understand that you are looking for, saving the Link's Text and using the `.select()` syntax you must use
 `doc.select("a[href"]);`
then you can use your current for loop.